# a little space on the top of website above form

Tags: html, css

I'm heading a problem with a little space that appears on top of my website's pages in all browsers. I have a form on the top. Here is my CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

form {
    margin : 0;
}

.formular {
    padding:  5px 40px 10px 40px;
    background-color: #6699cc;
    border-top: 0px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 ;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;


}
```

here is my index.php, I have a form on the top almost on every page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<title>Kto bude dnes odpovedať?</title>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<table align="center"><tr><td>

<SCRIPT>
function passWord()
{
 var pass1 = prompt('Zadajte administračné heslo','');
 if(pass1 && pass1.toLowerCase() == "0123")
 {
  alert('Správne heslo! Teraz môžete zmazať triedu.');
  return true;
  }
 else
 {
     alert('Zlé heslo!');
  return false;
  }
 }
</SCRIPT>


<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" class="formular" widht="100%"><tr><td>
<form action="vlozit.php" method="post">
  Nová trieda: <input type="text" name="nazov" placeholder="1.A, 3.B, 4.OA, ..." maxlength="4" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pridať triedu">
</form>

</td></tr></table>


<?php
```

.....

Comment: Can you provide your HTML, too, please?  A fiddle might help as well.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue please add more code http://jsfiddle.net/sC3La/

Comment: Try setting `cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3"` to `0` and what styles do you have for `.formular`

Answer (score 0):

try resetting your browsers so their not left to default. Here is a link to Eric meyers css reset. I tried with your code and it works. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/